# Qual è la differenza tra il mettere o l'omettere il tempo verbale infinito del verbo essere in un predicato nominale?

Tags: verbs, grammar

Il predicato nominale è formato da un verbo copulativo ( considerare, ritenere,  sembrare ecc...) e da un aggettivo o nome, che viene comunemente definito " predicato del nome".

Più di una volta, anzi molto spesso, mi è capitato di sentire  frasi in cui tra verbo copulativo e Predicato del nome veniva aggiunto il tempo verbale infinito del verbo essere, che è appunto "essere".

Solitamente però negli stessi casi in cui mi è capitato di sentire/leggere il tempo verbale infinito "essere" posto tra verbo copulativo e predicato del nome, mi è capitato anche di non vederlo affatto.

Vi metto 3 esempi per farvi capire:

1)Quella donna sembra triste/ sembra essere triste
2) il ragazzo che era ritenuto un grande talento/ che era ritenuto essere un grande talento ha deluso le aspettative.
3) lo consideravo un amico/ lo consideravo essere un grande amico.

Ci sono delle differenze? Se sì, quali?
Sono corrette entrambe le versioni o ci sono casi in cui è preferibile una o l'altra? Se sì, perché?

Vi ringrazio calorosamente in anticipo e vi auguro una buona pasqua.

Comment: Da parlante e scrivente di italiano che esprime un'opinione personale, questo uso di “essere” mi suona enormemente affettato, come a volersi dare un tono per sembrare più colti. Il caso peggiore è forse con il verbo “risultare” (“Fermato a un controllo stradale, risulta essere positivo...”). In tutti questi casi la frase senza “essere” ha lo stesso significato e suona molto più pulita.

Comment: In linea di massima sono d'accordo con @DaG anche se in alcuni casi, come nel primo esempio, secondo me l'aggiunta del verbo essere modifica il senso della frase: "*Quella donna sembra triste*" > in questo momento, per qualcosa in particolare; "*Quella donna sembra essere triste*" > in generale, come suo tratto caratteriale

Comment: @DaG: grazie mille della risposta.  Mi sono venute in mente delle costruzioni frasali simili, ma questa volta non col predicato nominale ma col predicato verbale: 1) la donna che pensavamo essere una pasticcera, faceva in realtà un altro mestiere. 2) Mario, che credevo essere un amico, mi ha poi tradito. Io in questi casi userei il che, ma mi piacerebbe se queste frasi sono corrette e intercambiabili con la versione con la congiunzione che